# erb in jquery causing "Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list"

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm using some erb to be appended to a page through jQuery. The page works fine when I take the erb out (the image_tag), but doesn't load properly with it in. Am I adding it in correctly?

The error in the console I'm getting is:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
```

Code sample:

```
        $('#stops').append(
          "<div class='bus-item-header col-xs-12'>" + 
            "<%= image_tag('compass.png') %>" +
            "<h2>" + stop.MonitoredVehicleJourney.PublishedLineName + 
            "</h2>" + "<br>" + "<span class='line-info'>"+ 
            currentStopOBA.name + "<br>" + 
            "TO: " + busDestinationRegex + "<br>" + "<br>" + "</span>"  
          + "</div>" + 
          "<div class='bus-item col-xs-12'>" + busDistanceAway + "<br>" +
            busStopsAway + " stops away" + "<p>" + "</div>"
         );
```

Any and all help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Does any of your variables have parenthesis?

Comment: Hi - yes, busDestinationRegex does have parenthesis since I'm using regex to replace some characters within that variable, but even if I change it out with a variable with no parenthesis, still seems to come up with the same error. Goes away as soon as i remove the entire image_tag.

Comment: Try removing the image tag from this section, and inputting it somewhere else in the plain html of the page, so that you can check the resulting raw html-output

Answer (score 0):

`image_tag` returns `img` tag which has double quotes in it. For this to work, you need to [escape](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/JavaScriptHelper.html#method-i-j) the quotes.

```
<%= j image_tag('compass.png') %>
```